# VertX 3.9.7 when i receive the form "throw exception" Size exceed allowed maximum capacity"

Tags: java, vert.x

I write small Rest Verticle. And submit on my Verticle Form. I receive
io.netty.handler.codec.http.multipart.HttpPostRequestDecoder$ErrorDataDecoderException: java.io.IOException: Size exceed allowed maximum capacity

If i send form data on a JsonObject all work good.

```
router.route().handler(BodyHandler.create());
router.post("/user/input").handler(this::complete);
```

if i want to submit a form should i use another one BodyHandler ??

My app uses applicalionn/json and application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Answer (score 2):

You get this exception when a form attribute has a size bigger than configured maximum.

You can change the value using [`setMaxFormAttributeSize`](https://vertx.io/docs/3.9.7/apidocs/io/vertx/core/http/HttpServerOptions.html#setMaxFormAttributeSize-int-)